# Open page in silverlight out of browser

Tags: silverlight-3.0, out-of-browser

Is there any way to open a page in the browser by clicking the app in out-of-browser mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HyperlinkButton works. I was trying with HtmlPage.Window.Navigate with no success. And because the button supports *content* it is simple to create something like a linked image.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Artur and simple way to do this is :

**1) Put HyperLink Button in your Silverlight page. 
2) Generate Click event and provide :**

```
hyperlink.NavigateUri = new Uri("Url",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

**3) Simply Run the Application and Click on HyperLink Button.**